# Showing onclick on DOM; should I hide it and if so, how?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, onclick

I am using the script beneath to make a toggle menu onclick. This works fine, but I don't know if it is good to use `Javascript` with an onclick attribute. Would this be a problem? It is visible now in the **DOM** if you use e.g. `Firebug`.

```
<a href="#" class="button" onclick="javascript:showElement('v-menu')">
<span>Click Here</span>
</a>
<ul id="v-menu" class="v-menu" style="display:none;">
</ul>
```

If it is harmful; how can I hide it? What should I have to  do?

PS: I am using Wordpress and jQuery did not work there. THat's why I used this method.

Comment: jquery works for wordpress! Try first to make it works with if you want to use it

Comment: I don't Think there is any problem to using Javascript

Comment: In what way do you mean "harmful"? You can use javascript yes, put you don't need the javascript: before it:
 `<a href="#" class="button" onclick="showElement('v-menu');">`

Comment: I meant for SEO reasons for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a serious problem with it, though a lot of people would recommend separating your JS from your HTML.

So you could alternatively give your anchor an ID and then at the bottom of your page do:

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("idname").onclick = function(){
        javascript:showElement('v-menu');
    };
</script>
```

... or put this in a script file and reference that using the `src` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

> I don't know if it is good to use Javascript with an onclick attribute

It isn't. It violates the [separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). See also [Progressive Enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) and [Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).

[`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) or an event abstraction library (included in YUI, jQuery and others) is generally preferred.

> It is visible now in the DOM

That isn't a problem. It is client side code. The client can see it.

> I am using Wordpress and jQuery did not work there.

Wordpress does not prevent you using jQuery.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I know that Wordpress isn't preventing me, but somehow it would not work.